# Pandas: replace column A with column B if B is not missing

Tags: python, pandas

I have question similar to a previous post. I want to replace missing values in A with B if B is not-missing. I've used a toy dataset.

```
#Create sample dataset
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df
df[df < 0] = 'NaN'
print(df)
Obs.     A         B
0        NaN  0.478943
1        NaN       NaN
2    1.96578   1.39341
3  0.0929079  0.281746
4   0.769023   1.24643
5    1.00719       NaN
6   0.274992  0.228913
7    1.35292  0.886429
8        NaN       NaN
9    1.66903       NaN

#Replace NaN in A with B if B is not NaN

df['A'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['A']) & pd.notnull(df['B']) == 0, df['B']*1, df['A'])
print(df)

obs      A         B
0  0.478943  0.478943
1       NaN       NaN
2   1.39341   1.39341
3  0.281746  0.281746
4   1.24643   1.24643
5       NaN       NaN
6  0.228913  0.228913
7  0.886429  0.886429
8       NaN       NaN
9       NaN       NaN
```

This code does the job. But why do I need pd.notnull(df['B']) == 0? If I write:

```
pd.notnull(df['B'])
```

instead, the code does not work correctly. The output from that is:

```
Obs.     A         B
0        NaN  0.478943
1        NaN       NaN
2    1.96578   1.39341
3  0.0929079  0.281746
4   0.769023   1.24643
5    1.00719       NaN
6   0.274992  0.228913
7    1.35292  0.886429
8        NaN       NaN
9    1.66903       NaN
```

I'm trying to understand the flaw in my logic. Any other simple intuitive code will be appreciated.

I basically need to do this simple operation for a very large dataset (100m obs+) so looking for a fast way (in terms of computer processing time) to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use `df.bfill(1)`?, selecting columns as needed

Comment: Not sure how backfill will help, since I want to use column B to replace missing values of column A. Can you be a bit specific on the code to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `'NaN'` with `np.nan` and apply `fillna` on column `A` using column `B`

```
df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)
df.A.fillna(df.B, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
          A         B
0  0.478943  0.478943
1       NaN       NaN
2  1.965781  1.393406
3  0.092908  0.281746
4  0.769023  1.246435
5  1.007189       NaN
6  0.274992  0.228913
7  1.352917  0.886429
8       NaN       NaN
9  1.669025       NaN
```

Comment: That worked and was quick on my computer so thank you! Still trying to get used to Python!